# Ultrapower theorem: reference request

Tags: model-theory

The ultrapower theorem states that every two elementary equivalent models have isomorphic ultrapowers (Shelah, Israel Journal of Mathematics, 1971, Vol. 10).

Are there other proofs than Shelah's?

Comment: This is actually a theorem of Keisler and Shelah. Keisler did it under GCH, and Shelah removed that assumption. See also https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Keisler-Shelah_isomorphism_theorem

Comment: Thanks Asaf. But Shelah's formulation is more powerful, if one is not interested in the size of the ultrafilter, isn't it? The first of his three statements of his paper yields, that any two elementarily equivalent models have isomorphic ultrapowers.

Comment: @JoelAdler Of course Shelah's formulation is more powerful, exactly in the sense pointed out by Asaf: Keisler and Shelah proved the same statement, but Keisler needed the extra assumption of GCH, while Shelah didn't use that assumption. The point, though, is that if you're looking for a simpler proof, you could start by reading Keisler's argument, which is much less technical. I'm not aware of any significant simplification of Shelah's argument (though no doubt others have rewritten it to be easier to read!).

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, since their proof is essentially the same as Shelah's, but you may enjoy reading the discussion in Chang & Keisler's *Model Theory*, section 6.1. They show first how to prove the theorem using GCH, then how to prove a stronger version of the theorem also assuming GCH, and then how to prove Shelah's result. Keisler's result is also discussed in Bell & Slomson's *Models and Ultraproducts*, section 7.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reference!